# Using Random Module to Administer DNA Mutations

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I would like to input a DNA sequence and make some sort of generator that yields sequences that have a certain frequency of mutations. For instance, say I have the DNA strand "ATGTCGTCACACACCGCAGATCCGTGTTTGAC", and I want to create mutations with a T->A frequency of 5%. How would I go about to creating this? I've heard that I can use the random module, but I'm not an experienced programmer, and a bit confused as to where to start. Any ideas on what I could do? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: `if random.random() < 0.05:` will be True 5% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite simple: go through the string and whenever you find a possible mutation point, mutate if the random number says to:

```
import random
def mutate(string, mutation, threshold):
    dna = list(string)
    for index, char in enumerate(dna):
        if char in mutation:
            if random.random() < threshold:
                dna[index] = mutation[char]

    return ''.join(dna)
```

If you wanted to be fancier, you could use a list comprehension:

```
import random
def mutate(string, mutation, threshold):
    return ''.join([mutation[char] if random.random() < threshold 
                                       and char in mutation else char
                                       for char in string])
```

Comment: This is a nice solution if T only ever mutates into A. Something more sophisticated may be required if T mutates into A 5% of the time, into G 15% of the time, and into C 23% of the time.

Comment: Yes the would be more sophisticated. Luckily due to how DNA works, there will only be one possible mutation per pair. So all that would need to happen is, instead of passing one threshold, have the mutation hold its threshold. Classes, gotta love 'em!

Comment: By 'one possible mutation' I mean that `T->A` and `A->T`. `T` will never mutate onto `C` or `G` :D

Comment: Can anyone create a code that has a random mutation frequency of a fixed percentage though? As Kevin commented initially?

Comment: hmmm...I am not sure about that Biology 101 statement. In nature any base can mutate into any base. This statement "Luckily due to how DNA works, there will only be one possible mutation per pair." is absolutely false! It is possible that given the constraints of your system, only A to T mutations are allowed, but this is not the case in Nature!!!!

Comment: This is actually based off of a lab experiment, so it's not "natural", per se.